# Can we create a sub-theme with multiple parent themes?

Tags: theming, 8

As title. I installed multiple 3rd party themes on my website. I'll activate them in random instance. Can I write a sub-theme which has multiple parent themes, but not ALL?

Comment: I am really just guessing here but I would think that if you properly set the parent theme in the info file for each theme you could chain them that way.

Comment: As I said they are 3rd party themes it's not good to modify the info file (although I can)

Comment: No, you can not. You can have a hierarchy of parents, but you can not have multiple themes, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually it's OK for me to create multiple child themes for each parent, just curious whether I can do so.

Comment: Multiple parent themes doesn't really make sense in and of itself. Can you add more information to the original question to explain what it is you want to pull from the multiple themes? Maybe we can provide a better solution.